# flutter pageview.builder duplicating texts

Tags: flutter, dart

in my flutter book app, I fetch a text from a JSON object and display it in `PageView.builder`. and after it fetches and displays on the first page and when it goes to the next page it duplicates the first page instead of displaying the remaining text file.

```
Container(
              height: height,
              width: width,
              child: PageView.builder(
                  itemBuilder: (context, index){
                    return RichText(
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      text: TextSpan(
                        text: '',
                        style: DefaultTextStyle.of(context).style,
                        children: <TextSpan>[
                          for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) ...{
                            TextSpan(
                              text: quran.getVerse(widget.id, i, verseEndSymbol: false),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 26,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                  fontFamily: 'kitab'),
                            ),
                            TextSpan(
                              text: quran.getVerseEndSymbol(i),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                                fontSize: 26,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                fontFamily: 'kitab',
                              ),
                            ),
                          }
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                  }),
            );
```

how can I split those text and display it on a page?

Comment: Actually it's infinity. you should write ```itemCount : 2``` in   PageView.builder

Comment: @MahdiBagjani I didn't specify the item count because it has dynamic count. and my problem is not with that it's when it display the text from JSON it shows each text index in separate page. for example JSON text index [0] = "first sentence is here", text index [1] = "second sentence is here", ...... text index [n] = "n+1th sentence here". if You got such text objects it creates 'n' pages for each. so how can I fix that

Comment: these array are in a sub array. you have to write that aray. ex:

```{
pages:[
{
"1 sentence here",
},
{
"2 sentence here",
},]
}```
then your length is ```pages.length```